# Shotwell imports some but not all my iPhone photos

Tags: downloads, iphone, shotwell

Little old lady here who may be asking a dim question but please bear with me!

I am on  Ubuntu 22.04.1 and update whenever suggested

I use Shotwell 0.30.14 – “Celle” for my photos

My iPhone is an 8 iOS 15.7

On attempting to download all my iPhone photos Shotwell is weirdly picky, for example, it has happily downloaded the pictures from 2-7/10/22 and 2-7 Nov 2022 but I cannot persuade it to download the rest of my holiday snaps...8-19/10/22

I tried for fewer photos, for photos and not videos, etc - no joy.
Looked up forums but cannot see something that mirrors my problem...

The error message is:

```
Import Results Report (Shotwell 0.30.14 @ 2022-11-08T09:07:45.430768Z)

I attempted to import 20 files. Of these, 0 files were successfully imported.

Photos/Videos Not Imported for Other Reasons:

/run/user/1000/gvfs/gphoto2:host=Apple_Inc._iPhone_aea192e2aa295e3593c652ca5b3ff19aa6effe6b/DCIM/202210__/IMG_2400.JPG
```

And then repeats for subsequent jpgs.

Do I perhaps need to update Shotwell, or is there anything else I can do to fix this problem?